# Phone stuck at boot animation after Andriod 6.0 Update

Tags: nexus-5, boot, 6.0-marshmallow

The four dot animation is endlessly running after Android 6 update in Nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on my Nexus 6 when I 'upgraded' to Android 5.0 and there was unfortunately nothing that could be done by the technicians I sent it to so they replaced it for me, free of charge.

What I would suggest you try first is doing a hard reset of your phone [(Instructions to do so here)](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en) and see if that works.  Failing that, talk to someone at Google (who'll probably tell you to do the same thing) and then, failing **that**, take it to a phone repair place and ask them to take a look at it for you.